# TimeStamp to String Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

**Repository**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM module m WHERE (:name is null or m.name ilike :name||'%') AND " +
            "(:code is null or m.code ilike :code||'%' ) AND (:is_active is null or m.is_active = :is_active)" +
            "AND (:create_date is null or m.create_date between to_date(':first_date','yyyy-MM-dd') and to_date(':second_date','yyyy-MM-dd')) ORDER BY id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<ModuleEntity> findAllWithFilters(String name, String code, Boolean is_active, Timestamp first_date, Timestamp second_date);
```

**Service**

```
public ArrayList<ModuleEntity> findAllWithFilters(String name, String code, Boolean is_active, Timestamp first_date, Timestamp second_date) {
        return moduleRepository.findAllWithFilters(name, code, is_active, first_date, second_date);
    }
```

**Entity**

```
@Column
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
Timestamp create_date;
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(FETCH_MODULES)
    public HashMap<String, Object> getModules(@RequestParam("page") int page,
                                              @RequestParam("limit") int limit,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "is_active", required = false) Boolean is_active,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "create_date_before", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd") Timestamp first_date,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "create_date_after", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="yyyy-MM-dd") Timestamp second_date){
        HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

        if (code != null || name != null || is_active != null || first_date != null || second_date != null){
            ArrayList<ModuleEntity> moduleFilters = moduleService.findAllWithFilters(name, code, is_active, first_date, second_date);
```

I need to find the range of creation date values ​​(from and to) but I can't convert String to Timestamp type, here is the error message:

Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Timestamp] for value '2022-12-21']

Please tell me how to convert

Answer (score 3):

you can use the Timestamp.valueOf() method. For example:

```
String dateString = "2022-12-27";
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateString);
```

Configure it according to your requirements.